# How do I create a macro (q<letter>) which goes to the end of a line and deletes one or two characters?

Tags: macro

I'm refactoring the logger code in my software.

The old log message ends with either `);` or just `;` at the end of a line and I want to remove those characters and add a new line with some additional data. Here are a few examples showing the endings:

```
SNAP_LOG_INFO("Some message");
SNAP_LOG_INFO("Some message ")(variable);
SNAP_LOG_INFO("Some message ")(func());
SNAP_LOG_INFO() << "Some message";

// Here is a special case, but I'm not trying to solve it because it's really rare
SNAP_LOG_INFO() << func();
```

I built my macro like this:

```
qs$xxi\n<< SNAP_LOG_SEND;\^[q
```

*(where `\n` is the Enter key and `\^[` is the escape key)*

That works great when the line ends with ");" but it deletes one too many characters when the old version ends with just ";".

How can I update my macro to make it work in both cases?

Comment: `%s/)\?;/^M<< SNAP_LOG_SEND` where `^M` is a `CTRL-V CTRL-M`

Comment: And this also should cover your special case: `%s/\((\@<!)\)\?;/^M<< SNAP_LOG_SEND`

Comment: When you write `%s/...` do you mean `:` rather than `%`?

Comment: `:%s/...` to target all lines

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `:substitute`, having:

```
SNAP_LOG_INFO("Some message");
SNAP_LOG_INFO("Some message ")(variable);
SNAP_LOG_INFO("Some message ")(func());
SNAP_LOG_INFO() << "Some message";

// Here is a special case, but I'm not trying to solve it because it's really rare
SNAP_LOG_INFO() << func();
```

You can use `:%s/\((\@<!)\)\?;/^M<< SNAP_LOG_SEND` to convert it to (Note, `^M` is a literal `CTRL-V CTRL-M`):

```
SNAP_LOG_INFO("Some message"
<< SNAP_LOG_SEND
SNAP_LOG_INFO("Some message ")(variable
<< SNAP_LOG_SEND
SNAP_LOG_INFO("Some message ")(func()
<< SNAP_LOG_SEND
SNAP_LOG_INFO() << "Some message"
<< SNAP_LOG_SEND

// Here is a special case, but I'm not trying to solve it because it's really rare
SNAP_LOG_INFO() << func()
<< SNAP_LOG_SEND
```

If that is what you want.

Comment: Okay, note that I also want to verify the results, so substituting in the entire file is problematic. I want to make the change to one log message at a time. Otherwise, the `(\@<!)` is a nice trick. I suppose it comes from perl...

Comment: use `:%s/.../.../gc` to make it "one change to one log message at a time"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to find where to go to the end of the line. For that we can actually use a search, but in a macro it replaces the current search. So you have to restore your current search as well if you use such.

The final macro looks like this:

```
qs/)\?;$\nC\n<< SNAP_LOG_SEND;\^[k/SNAP_LOG\nq
^ ^  ^    ^                   ^  ^^          ^
| |  |    |                   |  ||          +-- stop macro creation
| |  |    |                   |  |+-- restore my search
| |  |    |                   |  +-- go up one line
| |  |    |                   +-- ESCape to stop editing
| |  |    +-- delete end of line & start editing
| |  +-- make the parenthesis option in this search
| +-- search a search inside the macro
+-- start macro 's'
```

I use the `k` and do a search on my text so I can stay on the new line I just created. That way I can see if it worked. Otherwise it would go to my next instance which could be many pages below hiding the changes that just happened.